# Always install existing dependency version if present

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

In a yarn workspace project I want to make `yarn @workspace/name add lodash` use the range of `lodash` that is already in use in another workspace (if so) else it should pull in latest as per usual. I've hoped yarn constraints would solve this but they only seem to cover the enforcement bit - e.g. `yarn add` installs latest and then `yarn constraints` will fail checks.